# install python paver to ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, paver

I am trying to install paver to ubuntu (12.04) with this command

```
sudo apt-get install python-paver
```

I got this error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-paver
```

How do I  install paver in ubuntu then?

Comment: python-paver is not in the ubuntu repos `apt-cache search python-paver` returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/paver/paver/blob/master/README.rst#installation):

To install using pip,:

```
$ pip install -U Paver
```

To install using easy_install:

```
$ easy_install -U Paver
```

Answer (score 1):

I just uploaded a new Debian package to [my Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/~eighthave/+archive/flexget) for Ubuntu precise, quantal, raring, saucy, and trusty.  I also just uploaded it to the [official Debian repos](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-paver), so it should become part of the official Debian and Ubuntu repos again.